# Correctly awaiting Mongo's Find().ToList() in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm confused about what the correct way to call the following methods would be.
Ideally without awaiting inside the method itself, but while remaining asynchronous.

```cs
public Task<List<Item>> GetItemsByColor(string color)
{
    return collection.Find(x => x.Color == color).ToListAsync();
}
```

Will the entire method run asynchronous because the last method call `ToListAsync()` is asynchronous, or will it block because `Find()` is not `FindAsync()`?

And if `FindAsync()` should be called, is there a way to call it without the method requiring it's own async state machine?

Comment: FYI `.FindAsync` is equivalent to the synchronous method `.FindSync`, not the query builder method `.Find`.

Comment: ohh i see, so it really is for query building, meaning its okay to use Find(), yes?

Comment: Indeed. Using `Find` is OK.